# Hay alguna manera de llamar una función estática desde una librería sin escribir el nombre de la clase antes en C#?

Tags: c#, function, librería, static

Hace un tiempo me propuse en hacer una **librería** con un par de **funciones personalizadas** para hacer mi trabajo de manera mas sencilla pero a lo hora de **llamar las funciones** desde algún proyecto tengo q **incluir antes el nombre de la clase a la q pertenecen** es un proyecto sencillo q hasta ahora solo tiene una sola clase principal pero puede ser algo tedioso escribir el nombre de clase cada vez q voy a llamar una función, (las llamo muy seguido) hay alguna manera de evitar esto ?

Ejemplo:

```
namespace prueba
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
         funciones.Di_hola(); //lo q quiero evitar es tener q escribir el 'funciones.'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes crear una clase base de la cual todas las otras clases hereden, y esta clase base tiene el método que buscas. Por lo tanto, todas las clases 'hijas', podrán llamar esa función.

Comment: Prueba con `using static funciones;`

Comment: Pues podrias hacer que tu programa herede de tu clase funciones, class Program : functiones haciendo eso evitarios tener que llamar la clase, los metodos a los que puedes acceder serian los publicos o internos.